# how to set email Receptionit a NSString in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I am sending email from iphone app and i want that email sent to should be the value or address the var emailTO has should be in TO automatically.

```
     NSString*emailTO=@"ali@yahoo.com";


    [picker setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:emailTO]];
```

but it does not work any idea how to implement in this way thanks

Comment: Mean you not finding this `Email address` in `To` ?

Comment: please mark my answer as correct if it solved ur pblm

Comment: this looks alright, what's the behavior you're observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,@"ur Receipent data"]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ali@yahoo.com"];

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {

            MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            [mailViewController setToRecipients:array];

            [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }

        else
        {

            NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Hope will Help You.Note that you will need to add the MessageUI framework to your app.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

and

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@gmail.com"]];
[mail setSubject:@"Set Your Subject Here"];    
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

Use `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol:` Delegate Function for conform the result

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
}
```

### Description

```
setToRecipients:
```

Sets the initial recipients to include in the email’s “To” field.

```
- (void)setToRecipients:(NSArray*)toRecipients
```

Parameters
toRecipients
An `array` of `NSString` objects, each of which contains the `email address` of a `single recipient`.

Comment: what you're doing is this: an array containing a single object that is an array containing a string. how is that right?

Comment: I think First i create `NSMutableArray` and added list of email address as `String` objects. and as `setToRecipients` required `NSArray` so i cast it ?

Comment: When you do `[NSArray arrayWithObject:` you create an array containing another array. What you should do is: `[picker setRecipients: toRecipients]`. But that's no different from OP's code. So there's some other reason why it's not working.

Comment: This is wrong. You can't use sentinel with `arrayWithObject:`

Comment: But you are not doing anything different from what OP has already tried. This doesn't solve the problem really. Although, neither do any of the other "answers".

Comment: These days, there's no reason not to use the Objective-C literal syntax anyway: `@[ @"email@gmail.com" ]`. Shorter, clearer, and it's compatible back to OS X 10.0 if you want, as long as you use a modern compiler.

Comment: @Mar0ux I also wrote the Comment that what's the Problem you facing but no response that's i updated my answer with code to send `email` with `iOS App`

Comment: I think Now there is no reason For Down Vote and Thanks For Review this will help everyone improving the Skills.

Comment: @bit-whacker Looks much better now, I have removed my down-vote. But as I already said, I still don't see how this will solve OP's problem. Although, to be fair, OP hasn't shown us the whole code.

Comment: @Mar0ux Yeah and i commented first and no response found but on Nitin Answer he/she commenting as no relation between the comment and Question.

Comment: Yeah, I really hate it when people post a question and then just disappear/don't participate in comments.

Comment: @Mar0ux same here but what we can do but i am happy than i learned something. :)

Comment: That's the attitude I like to follow. Cheers mate!

Comment: @Mar0ux Good Luck Young Man..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open `iPhone` Email application, then use below code.So, you have not any need to add `MFMailComposeViewController`.

```
NSString *subject = @"";

NSString *body = @"";

NSString *address = @"test@gmail.com";

NSString *cc = @"";

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc, subject, body];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
                [picker setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"your email address"]];
                [self presentViewController:mailViewController  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
[picker setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:emailTO,nil]];
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can't use sentinel with `arrayWithObject:`